# Syntax to copy Opportunity Line Item Names throws error

Tags: apex

My Opportunities may have up to 4 Product line items.
I am trying to copy the 4 Opportunity Product names to 4 Custom text fields.

This throws an OpporunityLineItem not defined error and, I'm not sure how to find all line items

Thank you

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")} 

var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity"); 
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}'; 

record.Sample_Product_Name_1__c=OpportunityLineItem.PricebookEntry.Name; 
record.Sample_Product_Name_2__c= <<The next line item Name>>; 
record.Sample_Product_Name_3__c= <<The next line item Name>>; 
record.Sample_Product_Name_4__c= <<The next line item Name>>; 


sforce.connection.update([record]); 
window.location.reload();
```

This "should" work by placing everything into one field (Sample_Product_Name_1). Right?

This throws an "Invalid or Unexpected token" error

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}

var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.oli ='{Select Amount,CloseDate,Name,
     (Select PricebookEntry.Product2Id,
             TotalPrice,
             UnitPrice,
             ListPrice
      From OpportunityLineItems)
   From Opportunity}; 
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
record.Sample_Product_Name_1__c= record.oli;
sforce.connection.update([record]); window.location.reload();
```

Thank you for staying with me on this

This does not throw errors but it does not populate the field

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}

var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';

var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name 
From OpportunityLineItem 
WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");


    record.Sample_Product_Name_1__c=retriveOpptyLineItems.records[0].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name; 

window.location.reload();
```

Here is my latest attempt but it is now throwing an "Invalid or unexpected token"
Is this the same code that works for you?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}

var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name 
From OpportunityLineItem 
WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");


    record.Sample_Product_Name_1__c=retriveOpptyLineItems.records[0].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name; 


sforce.connection.update([record]); 
window.location.reload();
```

I am getting close, no errors and the field is partially populated. I think my problem was spaces in my query
This works but is only grabbing one of the two Opportunity line items on my opportunity. I think this is what you meant when you said loop through but, I don't know what that should look like.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name From OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");


record.Sample_Product_Name_1__c=retriveOpptyLineItems.records[0].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name; 


sforce.connection.update([record]); 
window.location.reload();
```

Updated code but, Invalid or unexpected token is back.

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name From OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");

record.Sample_Product_Name_1__c = '';
for(oppLineItem in retriveOpptyLineItems){
    record.Sample_Product_Name_1__c += oppLineItem.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name';
}

sforce.connection.update([record]); 
window.location.reload();

Comment: did you put update statement?

Comment: Is `Sample_Product_Name_1__c` a lookup field or a text field? Because if it's a lookup you need to pass an **Id** of the Opportunity Line Item and not just it's name..

Comment: Sample_Productt_Name__c is a text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code will be as follows:

```
var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name 
From OpportunityLineItem 
WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");


record.Sample_Product_Name_1__c=retriveOpptyLineItems.records[0].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
```

I have shown you to retrieve first record from the dataset.

You have to loop through the array to update records.

**Final Code**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name From OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");

var strProductNames = '';
for(var i=0; i<retriveOpptyLineItems.records.length ; i++){
strProductNames += retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name + ',';
}

//eliminate the last ','
if(strProductNames.length>0){
strProductNames = strProductNames.substring(0,strProductNames.length-1);
}
record.Sample_Product_Name_1__c = strProductNames;
sforce.connection.update([record]); 
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: his "should" work by placing everything into one field (Sample_Product_Name_1). Right?

This throws an "Invalid or Unexpected token" error

Comment: Thats the concept, you need to change query

Comment: do want change the question, it will create confusion

Comment: @Stavros see the updated answer

Comment: I've posted updated code. No errors but not populating field

Comment: Put alerts and see why it is not working

Comment: It is working perfectly at my Dev

Comment: Updated to include for statement but Invalid or Unexpected token error is back

Comment: Do you want me to write entire code for you? You are just copy and pasting code without using the logic

Comment: Check the updated ans. If you have any more question then ask a separate question. In case it is working for you then mark and close this so that other people can find this useful.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. My background is in VBA coding and, as you can probably tell, this was my first try at this. I am trying to learn while using your code. You have been extremely helpful and I am so appreciative of your time and patience. I wish you the very best

Comment: You can mark the answer and close this question